# Copy and paste files from one directory into current working directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to debug why i can't run this command

DOSKEY w-new=copy  C:\utils\ticket_templates\wordpress\readme.txt "%cd%/readme.txt"  /Y

I've tried both windows cmd as administrator and not

If i simply type C:\utils\ticket_templates\wordpress\readme.txt "%cd%/readme.txt" into the terminal it works but not if i use the w-new alias.

The w-new alias works inconsistently too. For example i can use it in /user/%USERPROFILE%/ dir but not in any of it's sub-directories.

I checked the file permissions of the destination and it's exactly the same as /user/%USEPROFILE%/

Any advice on debugging this is appreciated. Both source and destination are git repositories btw. As is /user/%USERPROFILE%/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `%cd%` is expanded when the `w-new` alias is defined, so the copy destination becomes constant - the current directory at the time of macro definition. You can see this by typing the following from the command line prompt:

```
doskey /macros
```

Also, you should not use `/` as a folder separator, use `\` instead. The `/` often works, but not in all situations.

You can prevent `%cd%` from being expanded during definition by inserting a caret within the variable name:

```
DOSKEY w-new=copy C:\utils\ticket_templates\wordpress\readme.txt "%^cd%\readme.txt" /Y
```

But why provide any target at all? You are simply copying a file to the current directory, using the original file name - that is the default behavior of COPY when no destination is specified.

So your macro can simply be:

```
DOSKEY w-new=copy C:\utils\ticket_templates\wordpress\readme.txt
```